# Inserting data from a tkinter treeview into a sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am creating a desktop program in Python using Tkinter, it is a simple dinner program that you select the products that the client wants and save it to a table number and sums the total values of each table number.

[The front page looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dff8.png).
I am sorry that it is in Portuguese, but

- 'comanda' means 'table number'
- 'Quantidade' means 'amount'

In my SQLite database I have four columns 'Comanda' , 'Status', 'Valor', 'Produtos', the first one has the 15 table numbers, the second is to tell if the table is active or inactive, the third is the sum of all the products that the client selected, and the fourth is supposed to give me a list of all the product names that the client has selected, but I am not being able to insert all the products of each table that were selected into a single cell in my db.

What I got so far is this:

```
def cmd():
  variavel1 = ncomandaE.get() #gets the table number
  variavel2 = "Aberto" #change the status to active

  for row in addprod.get_children():
     variavel4 = addprod.item(row)['values'][1] #gets the second column of the treeview which is the products name

     lite=c.execute("UPDATE comanda SET produtos = ? WHERE comandas = ?", 
     (str(variavel4), variavel1),)
```

It doesn't give me an error but only gives me the last product that the client selected.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `addprod.get_children()` is returning what you expect? Have you verified that `variavel1` is set to what you expect? Are you certain that `cmd` is being called at the appropriate time after data has been entered?

Comment: @BryanOakley I have tried a bunch of different ways to change the format when the data goes into the db, I printed the  'addprod.get_children()' and I got what I wanted, I think the problem is when the data goes into the database.

Comment: 'variavel1' is working fine, it gets the table number and inserts into the right row, 'cmd' is being attributed to a button and is also working fine.